# Javascript loop through JSON object

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, each

What I am trying to do exceeds my knowledge. Thank you all for your time and help, it is a great pleasure to have the support of such a large community of great developers.

**The problem**

I need to loop over an object (JSON response) to determine which data is true and then edit the html with the results.

**json object is**:

```
  var data = {
  "total": 4,
  "limit": 50,
  "questions": [{
    "date_created": "2015-06-29T18:24:25.000-04:00",
    "item_id": "MLA567045929",
    "seller_id": 186626557,
    "status": "UNANSWERED",
    "text": "Pregunta de Testeo, user 2.",
    "id": 3612747353,
    "deleted_from_listing": false,
    "hold": false,
    "answer": null,
    "from": {
      "id": 186625262,
      "answered_questions": 0
    }
  }, {
    "date_created": "2015-06-29T18:30:16.000-04:00",
    "item_id": "MLA567045929",
    "seller_id": 186626557,
    "status": "UNANSWERED",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "id": 3612938882,
    "deleted_from_listing": false,
    "hold": false,
    "answer": null,
    "from": {
      "id": 186625262,
      "answered_questions": 0
    }
  }, {
    "date_created": "2015-06-29T18:30:35.000-04:00",
    "item_id": "MLA567045929",
    "seller_id": 186626557,
    "status": "UNANSWERED",
    "text": "an est odio timeam quaerendum",
    "id": 3612752695,
    "deleted_from_listing": false,
    "hold": false,
    "answer": null,
    "from": {
      "id": 186625262,
      "answered_questions": 0
    }
  }, {
    "date_created": "2015-06-29T18:31:32.000-04:00",
    "item_id": "MLA567045929",
    "seller_id": 186626557,
    "status": "ANSWERED",
    "text": "Responder esta pregunta",
    "id": 3612753455,
    "deleted_from_listing": false,
    "hold": false,
    "answer": {
      "text": "Pregunta respondida",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "date_created": "2015-06-29T18:31:58.000-04:00"
    },
    "from": {
      "id": 186625262,
      "answered_questions": 1
    }
  }],
  "filters": {
    "limit": 50,
    "offset": 0,
    "is_admin": false,
    "sorts": [],
    "caller": 186626557,
    "seller": "186626557"
  },
  "available_filters": [{
    "id": "item",
    "name": "Item",
    "type": "text"
  }, {
    "id": "from",
    "name": "From user id",
    "type": "number"
  }, {
    "id": "totalDivisions",
    "name": "total divisions",
    "type": "number"
  }, {
    "id": "division",
    "name": "Division",
    "type": "number"
  }, {
    "id": "status",
    "name": "Status",
    "type": "text",
    "values": ["BANNED", "CLOSED_UNANSWERED", "DELETED", "DISABLED", "UNDER_REVIEW"]
  }],
  "available_sorts": ["item_id", "from_id", "date_created", "seller_id"]
};
```

**The result I'm looking for is**:

Of the data object, I need to extract `questions` with the status `unanswered` and the `id` field associated with these unanswered questions.

```
 "questions1":[{  "status" : "UNANSWERED",
                "id" : 3612747353}],
"questions2":[{  "status" : "UNANSWERED",
                "id" : 3612938882}],
 ...
```

Based on what I've searched, I've tried with loops, for in, and each without success.

Any suggestions or ideas on how I could achieve the desired result? I need to apply this example to several objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some handy list processing functions to simplify it conceptually. The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functions will help. The function I provided to filter tells it to only let through items that meet the condition of having an unanswered status. The function I provided to map turned all the objects that came out of filter into just their ids.

```
data["questions"].filter(function(obj) {
    return obj["status"] === "UNANSWERED";
}).map(function(obj) {
    return obj["id"];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = [];
for (var question in data.questions) {
  if (data.questions[question].status === "UNANSWERED") {
    results.push({
      "status" : data.questions[question].status,
      "id" : data.questions[question].id
    });
  }
}

// Now results contains an array of unanswered questions,
// with just their status & id.
```

Comment: some explanation of what you are doing will help the person asking the question

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the questions and save the ids you want to an array:

```
var questions = data.questions;
var unanswered = [];
for(var i = 0, len = questions.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(questions[i].status === 'UNANSWERED') {
        unanswered.push(questions[i].id);
    }
}
```

`unanswered` will be an array of unanswered question ids. You don't need to save the status; you know they are all 'UNANSWERED'.